# performed a small experiment with $watch in a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Tryed to compare the difference between different $watch argument passing:

Code:

```
angular.module('app', [])
    .controller( 'someCtrl', [ '$scope', function ( $scope ) {
        $scope.someVar = 'a';
    }])

    .directive( 'dirName', [ function() {
        var directive = {};
        directive.restrict = 'AE';

        var link = function ( scope, element, attrs ) {
            console.log('link!');

            scope.$watch( 'someVar', function() {
                console.log('var-string!');
            });

            scope.$watch( scope.someVar, function () {
                    console.log ('var with scope!');
                } );

            scope.$watch( function () {
                    return scope.someVar;
                }, function () {
                    console.log('function returns the var!');
                } );
        }

        directive.compile = function ( scope, element, attr ) {
            console.log('compile!');
            return link;
        }   

        return directive;
    }]);
```

Html:

```
<body ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="someCtrl">
        <div dir-name>{{someVar}}</div>
        <button ng-click="someVar='b'">b!</button>
    </div>
```

Onload/parse we have:

```
compile!
link! (this parts is quite clear for understanding)
var-string!
var with scope!
function returns the var
```

On click:

```
var-string!
function returns the var!
```

Can someone explain the difference between different setting types? What is preferred/faster/different cases/etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings are evaluated against the scope during an apply/digest cycle to check for changes. Functions are simply called during an apply/digest cycle to check for changes. Therefore, passing a string `s` is equivalent to passing a function like

```
function () {
   return $scope.$eval(s);
}
```

passing `$scope.someVar` will result in one of the above depending on whether `$scope.someVar` evaluates to a string or a function. It will not set up a watch for the `someVar` variable unless `$scope.someVar` is the string `"someVar"` or a function which returns `$scope.someVar`.